# How to unbrick Linksys EA6900?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

Recently I've got a Cisco Linksys router model EA6900, it was a gift from somebody who didn't know if it worked. When I first set it up, the Linksys LED logotype turned on but nothing happened, so I proceeded with a "30-30-30" reset, and after that the logo LED stays flashing at a constant rate. I can ping the router and get a response of under 1 millisecond, so I tried to upload the firmware via TFTP and no luck. All the manuals and tutorials that I've seen use a *.bin file, but the firmware file at official Linksys website is a .img, so I still wonder if that is the cause of the TFTP not working. The router apparently responds to every reset with a flash of the ethernet ports LED's, but can't get it to recovery mode or something else.

Also, it has a white 5 or 6 pins (I don't remember exactly) that maybe can be used with the Jtag method, but haven't found any specific information on the Net.

Can this router be de-bricked or should I use the parts for another useful thing?

Comment: If the logo's flashing it's probably trying to get an external IP, have you tried going to http:192.168.1.1 in a browser?

Comment: Yes, even doing an Nmap to the 192.168.1.1 IP gives me the port 80 enabled, but when I try to access the web interface I eventually end in a  "Cannot open page" error message.

Comment: I used one of these for about 9 months and had to replace it because it just wasn't stable and the wifi range was poor.  As far as firmware goes if you can't find the correct image from linksys (BTW linkys is no longer part of Cisco) you might try open source firmware like DD-WRT.